# Custom Sort and group java object on a field (not alphabetically)

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have a list of objects which I need to sort and group based on one field called ACTION.

```
public class MyClass {
   private String account;
   private String action;
  // other fields
}
```

Action could of 3 types DELETE, UPDATE AND ADD.

Expected list should have all the objects in order wherein all the objects with action type DELETE should be first in the list followed by action Type UPDATE and then ADD.

Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: You need to write a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: what happen if you have objects with same _action_? then you should compare with other property?

Comment: All the objects with same ACTION should be grouped together.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static List<MyClass> sortByAction(List<MyClass> items, String... actions) {
    List<String> sortedActions = Arrays.stream(actions).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Function<MyClass, Integer> actionIndex = item -> sortedActions.indexOf(item.action.toLowerCase());
    return items.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(actionIndex::apply)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static class MyClass {

    private final String account;
    private final String action;

    public MyClass(String account, String action) {
        this.account = account;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return account + '-' + action;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
List<MyClass> items = Arrays.asList(
        new MyClass("one", "ADD"), new MyClass("two", "UPDATE"), new MyClass("three", "DELETE"),
        new MyClass("four", "UPDATE"), new MyClass("five", "DELETE"), new MyClass("six", "ADD"));
List<MyClass> sortedItems = sortByAction(items, "DELETE", "UPDATE", "ADD");
System.out.println(items);          // [one-ADD, two-UPDATE, three-DELETE, four-UPDATE, five-DELETE, six-ADD]
System.out.println(sortedItems);    // [three-DELETE, five-DELETE, two-UPDATE, four-UPDATE, one-ADD, six-ADD]
```

***P.S.** As alternative way you can use `Map` to collect group of items*

```java
public static List<MyClass> sortByAction(List<MyClass> items, String... actions) {
    Map<String, List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (MyClass item : items)
        map.computeIfAbsent(item.action.toLowerCase(), action -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);

    List<MyClass> sorted = new ArrayList<>(items.size());

    for (String action : actions)
        if (map.containsKey(action.toLowerCase()))
            sorted.addAll(map.get(action.toLowerCase()));

    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear! however based on your latest comment, I think you can go with this:

`sortBase` is a sorted list based on your needed. then you can group your objects with action values and sort them based on `sortBase`

```
 List<String> sortBase = Arrays.asList("DELETE", "UPDATE", "ADD");
 Map<String,List<MyClass>> map =  list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getAction,
                    ()->new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(sortBase::indexOf)),
                    Collectors.toList()));
```

result:

{DELETE=[...], UPDATE=[.....], ADD=[...]}

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much Java, but if this were a Javascript problem I would loop through the array

```
var delateArr = [];
var updateArr = [];
var addArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i ++) {
  if(obj.action == DELETE) {
    deleteArr.push(obj);       // add obj to sub list with only DELETE
    objectArray.splice(i, 1);  // remove obj from main list
  }
  // repeat for UPDATE and ADD
}
```

then you should have three arrays containing only objects of the desired type and you can put them in any order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

First you can create an Enum for actions

```
enum Action {
    DELETE(1),
    UPDATE(2),
    ADD(3);

    private Integer priority;

    Action(Integer priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Integer getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

You can implement Comparable interface in you 'MyClass'. Here you can see I have compared by Actions priority value.

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{
    private String account;
    private Action action;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass o) {
        return this.action.getPriority().compareTo(o.action.getPriority());
    }
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

The you can sort by follow

```
list.stream().sorted(Comparable::compareTo).collect(Collectors.toList());
```